# npm Formidable Upload, use with JS FormData on client

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data, formidable

I wanna send a file to the server with FormData by drag and drop, and save it to disk with [Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) in node.

I used this code to send the file: https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable#example

and it works, my server saves the data, but I can't send it via js `FormData`. I wrote this code, but it doesn't parse the received data as files, and shows them like fields. The code is describe this better:

```js
// Client code
//inside drop event so i have files:

files = event.dataTransfer.files;
file = files[0];

reader = new FileReader();

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

reader.onload = function(evt) {
    var data, fd;
    data = evt.target.result; // it's real binary data on log
    fd = new FormData;
    fd.append("foo", "bar");
    fd.append("upload", data);
    uploadImage(fd);
}

uploadImage = function(data) {
    xmlHttp.overrideMimeType("multipart/form-data");
    xmlHttp.open('post', '/upload');
    xmlHttp.send(data);
}
```

It works and sends the data to the server, but `formidable`'s parse method logs like this:

```js
fields: {foo: 'bar', upload=''}
files: {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot's of changes, finally found a way!
This is my reader Code:

```
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

I changed type of file, from `buffer` to `Blob`, and it works:

```
arrayBufferToBlob: function(buffer, opt_contentType) {
    var uInt8Array;
    uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    return new Blob([uInt8Array], (opt_contentType ? {
        type: opt_contentType
    } : {}));
}
```

changes of client code:

```
//Changes of Client:
fd = new FormData;
data = arrayBufferToBlob(data);
fd.append("upload", data, "FileName");
```

And log of nodeJS server looks like:

```
fields: {foo: 'bar'}
files: {'fileName'}
```

I think Chrome (not tried on other browsers) HTML File tag uses Blob for HTML Forms to post... If you had idea, tell here!

Comment: Since you are uploading `Blob`s, by default, the user agent will set the name parameter of the Content-Disposition header in the file's multipart boundary to "blob" or something similar.  You can theoretically override this value with the 3rd parameter in `FormData.append`, but support for this is not very good.  For example, this is not supported in Safari or Firefox versions older than 22.  I suspect mobile browsers might also not support this, but I haven't confirmed.

Comment: tanX @RayNicholus, i'm not try to create a responsive web app, just for a demo, and it's a drag and drop upload, so not work in tablets or mobile devices! but tanX again for info! :)